# find and replace multiple items in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to FIND all such constructions:

`[m6][c green]Topic:[/c] football.[/m]

[m6][c green]Topic:[/c] tennis.[/m]

[m6][c green]Topic:[/c] swimming.[/m]`

and REPLACE them with these constructions:

`[m6][c green]Topic: football.[/c][/m]

[m6][c green]Topic: tennis.[/c][/m]

[m6][c green]Topic: swimming.[/c][/m]`

Thank you!:)

Comment: And how's that going?

Comment: I just want to "move" the closing color tag - [/c] - behind the whole text using find and replace..

Comment: The idea, though, is to show an effort. Post what you've tried and then we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try with this in notepad++:

```
(\[m6\]\[c green\]Topic:)(\[\/c\]) (.*?)\.(\[\/m\])
```

and replace with that:

\1 \3.\2\4

[Explaination is given here](https://regex101.com/r/5UmykI/1)

Comment: Try to learn regex from online tutorials and then apply those in the mentioned website. It will help you boost your regex experience

Comment: GREAT THANKS!!! the shortened version you posted here didn't work, but the longer one on that BRILLIANT website works perfectly. Thank you!;)

Comment: That was not shortened ... it is called not escaped, you need to escape special characters before you can apply them in regular expressions

Comment: You helped me incredibly:)

Comment: if that solves your problem, then you can help by accepting it as answer